# Objective-C/Xcode 6: Best way to have a Search Bar populate a table view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have  table view with a Search Bar above it. My intention is to have users enter a query in the search bar and have the table view populate with results - either when the user presses enter or as they're typing.

After reading a number of tutorials, I selected the *Search Bar and Search Display Controller* for the Search Bar. However, it seems this controller is less of an enter-query-then-display-results tool than a filter-existing-table-view-data tool. This means I'm coming upon a table view that already has all the data and is filtered as I type -- what I'd like is to come upon an empty table view and have it populate.

I was wondering if there was a way to use the *Search Bar and Search Display Controller* to achieve the effect I want or it there was a preferred way?

Comment: So what do you want to show before you do a search? Just a search bar without a UITableView?

Comment: I'd like to display and empty table view with a search bar above it.

Comment: Use UISearchController, which is new in iOS 8. It's much better than what came before.

Comment: @matt is there a preferred way of using the new UISearchBar? i'm confused because when i drag in a 'Search Bar and Search Display' object, it automatically is a deprecated UISearchDisplayBar object

Comment: See my github site for three different examples (four, actually): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples - you want the ones called SearchableTable.

Comment: Hi @HarlanKellaway I've been searching about what I want to do and your question is exactly that. Could you share with me your coding sample as a guideline? What I've done is in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313349/search-in-pfquerytableview-not-working). Thank you very much.

Comment: @sanitlee I actually ended up going with the other type of search bar - just an independent search bar and an independent table view that is populated by the search bar's delegate

Comment: @HarlanKellaway would you mind to share your code for this part with me as an answer to [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313349/search-in-pfquerytableview-not-working)? That would help me out finally. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `UISearchDisplayController` you'll have two `UITableView`s. The one in your search view controller. So assuming you are hooking up both `UITableView`'s dataSources to your `UIViewController`, just check which table is being passed in and return nothing if it's not for the search.

For example

```
- (NSArray *) _sectionArrayForTable:(UITableView *) tableView {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // Return your search results
    }

    // Show nothing when not searching
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's it - the 'return 0'; was what i was overlooking. Thank you!

Comment: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView is deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: @venky is there a preferred way of using the new UISearchBar? i'm confused because when i drag in a 'Search Bar and Search Display' object, it automatically is a deprecated UISearchDisplayBar object

Comment: @HarlanKellaway 
This may helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826332/searchdispalycontroller-deprecated-ios-8

Answer (score 2):

These two Ray Wenderlich tutorials are great for learning how to implement search into your UITableViews.

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view) covers the basic Search Bar with Objective-C.
[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift) covers the Search Bar using Swift.

Basically (very basic implementation level here) you will want to know if you are searching or not. If you are not searching, in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method you can return 0, otherwise return the count of the results. Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you can customize the cell that is being displayed based upon the results.

Answer (score 0):

When the text changes, you will want to determine which results to show for that string and update some array or dictionary.  Implement the tableview datasource methods to show the contents of that array/dictionary and call reload table when the text changes