# Search in PFQueryTableView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchbar, pfquery

I have PFQueryTableView with UISearchBar to search users from my user class on Parse server but I never get it working. Here is my code:

**SearchViewController.h**

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface PAWUserSearch1ViewController : PFQueryTableViewController
@end
```

**SearchViewController.m**

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "PAWAppDelegate.h"

@interface SearchViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
@end

@implementation SearchViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = [PFUser parseClassName];
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = NO;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
        self.objectsPerPage = self.objects.count;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    NSLog(@"searchbar text --> %@", self.searchBar.text);

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    if ([self.searchBar.text length]!=0) {
        PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
        [userQuery whereKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey matchesRegex:self.searchBar.text modifiers:@"i"];
        [query whereKey:kPAWParseUserKey matchesKey:@"objectId" inQuery:userQuery];
    } else {
        [query whereKeyExists:@"featuredNote"]; //show only users with location detailed
    }

    return query;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"number of users --> %i", self.objects.count);
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    // display user name
    NSString *userNameWithLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@ -%@", [self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey], [self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"featuredNote"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = userNameWithLocation;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70.0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set nav
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];

    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = NO;

    // Hide the search bar until user scrolls up
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar
                                                          contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
    self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;

    self.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Username", nil);
}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"search pressed!!!!!!");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    [self loadObjects];
}
@end
```

This code displays all users if their "featuredNote" exits - this part works fine but when I search it does't show search results. I type a keyword in search box and when I hit search on keyboard, the ***searchBarSearchButtonClicked*** method is fired but that is it. I expect ***queryForTable*** to be called but it is not. As a result, the table still shows all users as original. What have I done wrong or am I missing something here? Please help out. Thank you so much.

**Update**

Since I have replaced *[self.tableView reloadData];* with *[self loadObjects];* and I am able to call ***queryForTable*** after ***searchBarSearchButtonClicked***. However, ***tableView numberOfRowsInSection*** still always returns zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code [you asked for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305791/objective-c-xcode-6-best-way-to-have-a-search-bar-populate-a-table-view?noredirect=1#comment46854734_26305791) from a project with a similar implementation need. I ended up using a `UISearchBar` with a separate `UITableView` to display the results. Make sure to make the proper Storyboard connections for the `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` when implementing. Also, the search bar's `delegate` should be set to the `ViewController` and the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` should be set to the `ViewController`.

```
static NSString * const kSearchResultsTableCellReuseIdentifier = @"SearchResultsTableCellReuseIdentifier";

@interface ViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *searchResults;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *searchResultsTable;
@end

@implementation ViewController

...

#pragma mark - Protocol conformance

#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate methods

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [self dismissSearch];
    }
    else
    {
        [self handleSearchForString:searchText];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // any logic related to Search button being clicked
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.searchResults count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.searchResultsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kSearchResultsTableCellReuseIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kSearchResultsTableCellReuseIdentifier];
    }

    // Search result text to be displayed in table
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].name;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // any logic for when a cell in the search results table is selected

    [self dismissSearch];
}    

#pragma mark - Helpers

- (void)handleSearchForString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    // any logic for retrieving search results as an NSArray we'll call `results`

    self.searchResults = results;
    [self.searchResultsTable reloadData];

}

- (void)dismissSearch
{
    self.searchBar.text = @"";

    [self.searchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder)
                      withObject: nil
                      afterDelay: 0.1];
}

@end
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the query but you are not telling it to do a search, you need to do something like this :

```
[query whereKeyExists:@"featuredNote"];//this sets the query

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    //Your code here


}];//this PERFORMS the query
```

Comment: You're right, so I have implemented code for search in the query block as you suggested but there's a problem. Once I hit search, it shows error **'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'** But thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: why do you have two queries? PFQuery *query = [PFUser query]; and PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query]?. userQuery is never used in this code. why is it there?

Comment: can you post more of your code? if you are getting this error is is most likely you are trying to perform more than one operation on the same Parse object at the same time.