# Insert a UISearchBar in IOS 8, Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, uisearchbar

What is the best most efficient way to implement a `UISearchBar`?

I check all over the internet, and all the tutorials are for the `ios 7` version, and a lot of the methods are deprecated in `ios 8`. Can someone please provide a library, or a sample of how to implement a `searchBar` in xcode for `ios 8`?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Please ask a specific question, including applicable error messages - See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question is What am I supposed  to do about the deprecated codes when I implement the UISearchBar? I wrote deprecated at the parts that are deprecated. ex. self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the deprecated methods and properties.  The documentation will normally provide the recommended alternative

Comment: For example -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826332/searchdisplaycontroller-deprecated-ios-8

Comment: Yes I did look at the a number of times, and it does not give a clear answer.

Comment: It is pretty clear - Use `UISearchController` not `UISearchDisplayController`.  If you are wanting to support versions prior to ios8 then you need to live with the deprecation warnings

Comment: I understand and read that part previously, but I cant implement it in my code? ex.if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchresultsArray count];

    } else {
        return [array count];
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67599/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do the same you are doing a few months ago. So, I found this on GitHub: https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController
Download/clone it and you'll be able to see how to use UISearchController with UITableView and UICollectionView. It has everything you need to upgrade from UISearchDisplayController to UISearchController. The UISearchController documentation is also really helpful.
If you also need to support iOS 7(something I personally recommend if you are really about to deploy your app to the App Store) do this:

```
if([UISearchController class]){
//Create an UISearchController and add it to your UITableViewController
}else{
//Create an UISearchDisplayController and add it to your UITableViewController 
}
```

Note: You'll have to do everything programatically if you want to support both versions of iOS.

Best regards,

Gabriel Tomitsuka

Comment: I actually did come across that earlier, I'm just not sure which file to read from. It has so many different files.

Comment: Use the MasterViewController_TableResults and the MasterViewController_FilterResults files.