# Table search using UISearch controller for iOS 8 or later

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

> Any one could help to share sample code for table search functionality for iOS 8 or later because searchDisplayController is deprecated

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826332/searchdisplaycontroller-deprecated-ios-8  ?

Answer (score 0):

Download the sample project given in [this](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController) link.
Hope that helps. It demonstrates the use of the UISearchController class based on tableView search.

Answer (score 0):

I found this "UISearchDisplayController has been replaced with UISearchController". So let try UISearchController.

Answer (score 0):

1. you first create one textfield(as text) and one table view(as tableView) and their delegates in viewcontroller.h files
2. and wirte this code in viewcontroller.m file

> #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{

NSMutableArray *tableData;

NSMutableArray *tableArray;

NSMutableArray *dummyArray;
NSMutableArray *searchArray;
NSString *searchTextString;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//set the selector to the text field in order to change its value when edited
[self.text addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
//here you set up the methods to search array and reloading the tableview
[self setupData];
[self updateSearchArray];
[self.tableView reloadData];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
_tableView.allowsSelection=NO;
self.text.delegate=self;
}
//setting up the data sourch for the mutable array
- (void) setupData {
dummyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Values:", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Apple", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 2 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dummy", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 3 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mango", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Brown", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"jumps", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"hello", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
[dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"shahzaib", @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0f/255.0f green:220.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
return YES;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
[_tableView setHidden:YES];

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];

if ([_text.text isEqualToString:@""] ||[_text.text isEqualToString:@" "])
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"TextField is empty now!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
else
{

    [dummyArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_text.text, @"name" , @"image1.JPG", @"image" , @"dummy 1 description textview", @"description", nil]];
     [_tableView reloadData];
    searchTextString = textField.text;
    [self updateSearchArray];
}
return YES;
}

#pragma - mark TextField Delegate Methods
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 [_tableView setHidden:NO];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [searchArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if( cell == nil ){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DummyDetail" sender:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
self.text.text=[[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Search Methods

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField
{

searchTextString = textField.text;
[self updateSearchArray];
}
//update seach method where the textfield acts as seach bar
-(void)updateSearchArray
{
if (searchTextString.length != 0)
{
    _tableView.allowsSelection=YES;
    searchArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for ( NSDictionary* item in dummyArray )
    {
        if ([[[item objectForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchTextString lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [searchArray addObject:item];
        }
       else
       {
            //NSString *notfound;
            //notfound=@"not found";
            //[searchArray addObject:notfound];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    searchArray = dummyArray;
    _tableView.allowsSelection=NO;
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

its a complete search,i think this one help you, tell me if you need more help ...

Comment: Thanks Shahzaid. But I didnt get it well. Would you please provide any demo code.