# appearanceWhenContainedIn warning for ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some warning which worked well in ios 7 & 8.  While we work with iOS 9 its gives me a warning.

**This is the warning :**

> 'appearanceWhenContainedIn:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use +appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses: instead

So I used this code :

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Instead of this code:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But when I used I got the error:

**Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2**

> warning: `'base64Encoding' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0`

**In below code:**

```
 NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]];
```

> warning:  `'searchDisplayController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0`

**In below code:**

```
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchText scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                                   objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
```

> warning: `'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h`

In below code:

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

I am working with iOS9. I need to remove all these warnings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you command-click on the method in question, you will jump to the definition, and in many cases the deprecation notice should tell you what method to use instead. For example, `+appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:` now takes an `NSArray` of `Class` objects instead of a `va_args` list of `Class` objects.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:` wants an `NSArray` of classes. Thus:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Instead of `base64Encoding` (which has been deprecated since iOS 7.0 so that's not a new warning for you), use this:

```
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
```

Regarding `searchDisplayController`, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25826332/77567).

Regarding `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, the error message is clear. You need to rewrite that part of your app to use an `NSURLSession` and its `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` method. There are lots of helpful resources for this on the Internet, like this objc.io article: [“From NSURLConnection to NSURLSession”](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/).

Comment: Hey rob, base64encoding worked well.But that `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:` got 2 errors: `Expected identifier` i tried to add but the errer is still.. Second error: ` No known class method for selector 'appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:setTextColor:'`

Comment: I got the brackets slightly wrong. I bet you can figure out how to fix it if you just look at it for a minute.

Comment: one question- i used synchronous - dies it need any delegate methods to add to solve my waring, Because i haven't use any delegate method ...For my question - 4